# Vue.js v-if toggle for show/hide nav

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a nav that you can show/hide toggle by clicking on an button. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am still learning Vue so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code from navigation.vue:

```
<template>
   <div>
    <nav v-if="seen">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#front">front</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <p><button v-on:click="seen = !seen">Toggle</button></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data: {
        seen: true
      }
    }
</script>
```

Importing the navigation in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    <app-front></app-front>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
    import Navigation from './components/navigation.vue'
    import Front from './components/front.vue'
    import Footer from './components/footer.vue'

    export default {
      components: {
        'app-navigation': Navigation,
        'app-front': Front,
        'app-footer': Footer
      },
      data () {
        return {
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With components, your `data` property needs to be a function.

```
data(){
  return {
    seen: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I put the data property in navigation.vue or App.vue? Tried both and I still cant get it to work :S

Comment: @ThomasAlexanderWoolff Well, in this case in the Navigation.vue. I'll throw together an example.

Comment: This is what I have: 

`<template>
   <div>
    <nav v-if="seen">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#front">front</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <p><button v-on:click="seen = !seen">Toggle</button></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          seen: true
        }
      }
    }
</script>`